# UINavigationBarButton not working when using customView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uinavigationbar, custom-view

I would like to make a custom UIBarButtonItem that contains both image and text and also customise(reduce) the UIButton tap area. To achieve this programmatically, I am using the following code snippet. But UIButton disappears when added in UIView as subview. Could somebody guide me what is wrong ?
To reduce tap area of bar button, I am embedding custom UIButton in custom UIView.

```
//Set Navigation Bar
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 64)];

//Set title if needed
UINavigationItem * navTitle = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];
navTitle.title = @"";
UIView *customBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220,0,50,40)];
customBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

//Here you create info button and customize it
UIButton * tempButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
tempButton.frame=CGRectMake(240,2,40,40);
[tempButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"offline_bk.png"]
         forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//Add selector to info button
[tempButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onTapDone:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[customBackView addSubview:tempButton];
[customBackView bringSubviewToFront:tempButton];
UIBarButtonItem * infoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customBackView];

//In this case your button will be on the right side
navTitle.rightBarButtonItem = infoButton;

//Add NavigationBar on main view
navBar.items = @[navTitle];
[self.view addSubview:navBar];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your tempbutton is going out of bound of custom back view. You set the y origin value to  2 and x origin value to 240 which is causing button to go out of bound of custom back view.

Try this code:

```
 UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 64)];

    //Set title if needed
    UINavigationItem * navTitle = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];
    navTitle.title = @"";
    UIView *customBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)];
    customBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    //Here you create info button and customize it
    UIButton * tempButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    tempButton.frame=CGRectMake(4,2,40,40);
    [tempButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"offline_bk.png"]
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //Add selector to info button
    [tempButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onTapDone:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [customBackView addSubview:tempButton];
    [customBackView bringSubviewToFront:tempButton];
    UIBarButtonItem * infoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customBackView];

    //In this case your button will be on the right side
    navTitle.rightBarButtonItem = infoButton;

    //Add NavigationBar on main view
    navBar.items = @[navTitle];
    [self.view addSubview:navBar];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:navBar];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the UIButton image is not visible, we cannot identify if the button exists at the right corner.

Comment: You can.You can use view debugger to traverse view hierarchy for existence of button.May be problem in size of image.Try image file according to size of button

Comment: I have tried with dummy image and it is working.Make sure image which you are using is correct in resolution and added correctly to bundle of project

Comment: Do I need to add image in Assets ? I am adding image of 32*32 but it is not visible.

Comment: No.But for retina display you need image of 2x resolution, Means for your button you need image of 80*80 and make sure when you add image to bundle it should be get listed under Target->Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources